# Unsplash API: How to retrieve Access_Token for authenticated access-login by browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I needed to submit an approved-account access to Unsplash API, so as to access certain links for access approval. Given that the replies from the support team has taken more than a few days, I would just like to seek out additional help to resolve in **retrieving the access_token for new requests-submissions via GET / POST methods**.

The original website was working perfectly, till when I had wanted to get ready for submission for production stage and had wanted to prepare potential increases in requests to the Unsplash API.

However, the approval process entailed certain setup criterial, which I totally missed during my development phase and sought to iron out as soon as possible. **One of the key component is to resolve your UTM links**, which you may find here as the ideal reference: https://help.unsplash.com/en/articles/2511315-guideline-attribution.

My challenge then was that I had attempted to use the official javascript API, **Unsplash-Javascript-API** (https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js#authorization), in an effort to make the authentication / request processes simpler for my webapp to call.

Though most GET requests do work, given that a specific URL of links via "*download_location*" (https://help.unsplash.com/en/articles/2511258-guideline-triggering-a-download), has to be used instead, it will then require an authenticated request per new submission request by the webapp.

The final challenge then is that apparently it is not clear how the official Unsplash-Javascript-API actually pulls the "authenticated" request, as I was unable to find it on the website, so that I may retrieve the current-*access_token* for requests' usage.

The basic codes I am using via the API is the following, however I am confused what is the actual maximum request I may pull per page, I am hoping to get 100 returned images' details, but only gotten a maximum of 30 per time. Anyone can also help to confirm is there a workaround to increase this 30 to 100?

---

Retrieving a Collection of Photos

```
unsplash.collections.getCollectionPhotos(urlAPI, 1, 100, "Popular")
                .then(toJson)
                .then(jsonData => {
                    console.log("jsonData", jsonData);

                });
```

So, currently my website is unable to launch for nearly 1 week plus, as I am just awaiting the final confirmation or additional help from the customer support end of the official Unsplash Team.

Hopeful that someone may help to assist me in clarifying the codes so that at least I can get one step closer to sorting this "official authenticated" process out, and take away one lesser step to getting my approval access for production ready.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Given multiple tries. I wasn't able to retrieve the Access_Token reply, given that there is a pre-authorization step that I wasn't able to find any working solution to.

The current and clear limitations to the API are:

---

- Maximum of 30 images request per GET request.
- The official javascript API, Unsplash-Javascript-API (https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js#authorization) works but there is not clear or easy way to retrieve the "Access_Token" for a session usage.
- Multiple async AXIOS / FETCH requests may not be "compiled successfully" when using ReactJS ContextProvider function prior to the first render. Therefore, an empty array will be shown instead on the final initial render.

---

Ultimately, my chosen solution is current to break down the images list to the most priority, with the limitation of only 30 images on retrieval, and still store into the original collection and retrieve it.

The other alternative is to actually download and load the images to your own server to load it, which may also be a faster route.

---

Sadly enough, the Unsplash API team doesn't response as frequently to assistance and my last contact was roughly 1 month ago, though I have attempted to update to their requirements but there were no feedback thereafter.

Thus, it will tentatively be better for you to just build an alternative solution than to rely on the team for a feedback, unless you are a paying client.

Good luck to the others on this! Cheers!